# How can I show the variant of a device in a symbol in EAGLE?

Tags: eaglecad, symbol

I am creating a device with multiple variants in EAGLE. The associated symbol should show the variant as well, so that it will be directly visible on the schematic.
I know how to add e.g. >VALUE or >NAME to a symbol and how to show attributes, too. But I can't find a way to show the variant name.

Comment: What is *variant* in your understanding? There're two things - technology and package, are you talking about package?

Comment: @Anonymous : In the device screen you can add multiple packages. Each time you add one, a variant is created, which can be named. E.g. a microcontroller variant with same package and pinout but more memory. Maybe I could use the technology field for this as well, but it would be more work to provide the attribute information eacht time.

Answer (score 1):

> In the device screen you can add multiple packages. Each time you add one, a variant is created, which can be named.

I think names speak for themselves, but anyway let's look into them. For this just open `74-xx-little-us.lbr` in the library editor and then device `74*1G00` as an example.

- Package: you already know that it is footprint of the device on the board;
- Variant: the identification of the package in relation to the current device;
- technology: the intrinsic capability of the device.

Go to schematic editor, and import `74AHCT1G00DBV`from the list of 74*1G00 from this `74-xx-little-us.lbr` library.

This name `74AHCT1G00DBV` is composed in the following way:

- 74*1G00;
- AHCT put instead of * as *technology*;
- DBV is added at the end as variant.

Now look into the library editor again. Right click onto package/variant line in the subwindow to the right, you will see that:

- you can rename this selected variant (in other words, change package suffix);
- you can add, remove or assign technologies for the device available in this selected package (variant).

In your example with microcontroller, which may have different RAM size:

- create symbol for it, all packages/technologies/variants will have same symbol;
- create packages this MCU is available in, add them to the list in library editor, for example N for DIP and D for SO;
- add each package *twice* to the device, give each package in library editor's package/variant subwindow unique package identification, e.g. "KN" and "KD" for 16 KB RAM, and "YN" and "YD" for 32 KB RAM;
- create technologies available, for example "42" for 3.3 V, and "46" for 5 V device;
- name device as PIC*K22.

And in schematic editor you will have the following devices in the list available (of course depending on your technology assignments)

```
PIC42K22KN
PIC42K22KD
PIC42K22YN
PIC42K22YD
PIC46K22KN
PIC46K22KD
PIC46K22YN
PIC46K22YD
```

which will represent **complete device identification marking**.

The example above is (almost) out of the blue, because I like Microchip :)

(hopefully I did not make any logical mistake above, and I am sure you will figure out things yourself).

Comment: That helped my understanding a lot! Your solution will show up in the value field of the symbol then. Is there another option to show the devicename on the symbol? I would like to use the value field for e.g. resistance values too.

Comment: You already know >NAME keyword (in the *Names* layer) and >VALUE keyword (in *Values* layer). Resistor device, most probably, is already having its >NAME field defined, but it is just empty. Open *info* window on the resistor device in schematic editor, and define its value.